# How to work with dynamic SerializedName annotation?

Tags: java, android, gson, realm

I have a json that i transform with gson in a realm model, over the annotaion @SerializedName.

But sometime in the json, there is a unknown key, that i want to serilized to a string.

```
public class example extend Realmobject{
@SerializedName("example1")
@Expose
private String exampleNr1;
@SerializedName("example2")
@Expose
private String exampleNr2;


private String someOtherValue;
Getter / Setter here...
```

}

The Json is like this

```
[
{
"example1": "1234",
"example2": "1234",
"x": "dynamic"}, {
"example1": "1454",
"example2": "165456",
"xy": "dynamic"}]
```

Now i will to Serialized the x and xy Key (somtimes is named xyz and so on) to the someOtherValue String.
Over the @SerializedName(value="", alternate={""}) I have no chance, because, i dont know the name of the field.

i Serialize this over
List woList = gson.fromJson(parentArray, 
new TypeToken>() {}.getType());

Answer (score 0):

You could translate it to a JSONObject first. Then you can loop through the set of keys inside the JSONObject.

```
    JSONObject json = gson.fromJson(stringJson, JSONObject.class);
    Iterator<String> set = json.keys();
    while(set.hasNext()) {
        String dynamicAttributeName = set.next();
    }
    json.get(dynamicAttributeName); //to get the value
```

Comment: This is a good method, But i have a array with over 100000 objects and with this method, the speed and Performance going down. I need a tip for manipulate the @serializedname string, so that i dont Go in in the object du control the key. I get the unknown key bevor the json comes, help this?

Comment: There must be a way for you to find out all the possible attribute names returned by the API?

Comment: If there are 100000 objects, then ditch GSON and use a streaming api.